# Want to order eventbrite events list so upcoming events show up first

Tags: php, eventbrite

How can I modify the following call so upcoming events show up first.  Currently the order is very random; I need to show most current events at the top and any past events should not be showing...

```
    <div class="events-links">

    <?
    include "eventbrite/Eventbrite.php"; 
    $authentication_tokens = array('app_key'  => 'APP_KEY',
                       'user_key' => 'USER_KEY');
    $eb_client = new Eventbrite( $authentication_tokens );
    $events = $eb_client->user_list_events();
    ?>

    <span class="inspirational">Upcoming Events</span>
    <?= Eventbrite::eventList( $events, 'eventListRow'); ?>
    </div>
```

- these are not my tokens; I changed them prior to posting to just random characters :)

Comment: I hope those aren't your actual tokens :)

Comment: What does `var_dump($events)` look like?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the `user_list_events` method, you can filter your results by adjusting the `event_statuses` field. Valid options include: live, started, or ended. To display only upcoming events, for example: `event_statuses=live`.

The results will display from soonest upcoming event to event happening farthest in the future.

Comment: thank you - where do I adjust this field (in the code I have)

Comment: You can look in the `examples` directory for the PHP client: https://github.com/ryanjarvinen/eventbrite.php/blob/master/examples/attendee-list-example.php

Comment: This example in here is the exact code that I pasted up above in my question.....

Answer (score 1):

After you fetch `$events`, use `usort` to sort the array.

**usort**: http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

```
$events = $eb_client->user_list_events();
usort($events, function($a, $b) {
    $adate = $a->start // or $a['date'] or $a->whatever it is
    $bdate = $b->start // or $a['date'] or $a->whatever it is
    if ($adate < $bdate) return -1;
    if ($adate > $bdate) return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

Alternatively, you can contact your account manager if you have one.

(Disclosure: I work for an EB competitor)

Comment: This code puts out an error, I have error logging turned off though

Comment: Not sure how to utilize this then; my experience is in front-end development (html/css/jquery/design); I am not sure how I can deploy the usort function

Comment: What does var_dump($events) look like?

Comment: It spits out the full event as listed on eventbrite.com for each event; it's too much content and too many parameters to neatly paste on here...